# Eclipse: Info: Nothing to build for [Project Name]

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide

I'm currently new to C++ and I created a Hello World in Eclipse C/C++ but all It says in the Console is: Info: Nothing to Build for [project name].... How to fix this? Yes, I have done everything like setting up the variables of my mingw and all that and I still get this message on my Console... I searched all of this stuff on the Internet but It didn't quite help...

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: It means there is no need to recompile any modules. Does this happen when you run the project?

Comment: jorn vernee, yes...

Comment: pritam, it only says: info, nothing to build for [project name]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your console view set to the wrong console.

There is a build console and the normal output console. It should switch to the output console when running, automatically (but, any ways, it didn't).

On the console view there is a set of buttons, one of which looks like a little monitor. If you click on the little arrow next to that you can select the output console for your program:

[image]

Comment: Wow! I was like finding This Problem for like 2 Years now and You Finnaly saved me! Thanks man, Really appreciate it :D

Comment: Finnaly, Because of you man, I can finnaly write C++ Programs lol