# Simple C++ output error: 'Info: Nothing to build for project <insert project name>'

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am very new to learning the simple and basic concepts of C++ and have started looking through and learning video tutorials on YouTube. At the moment I have built and created a simple project based on the readily default 'Hello World' output program that is for some reason displaying a strange error onto the output window that states 'Info: Nothing to build for project '. I am curious to wonder a possible solution for fixing this fault for I have already installed all relevant MinGW packages from the installation window alongside run the 'Build Project' setting from the project tab. Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse: Info: Nothing to build for \[Project Name\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419689/eclipse-info-nothing-to-build-for-project-name)

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Please post a link to a screenshot! And don't be disheartened - in my experience, it's fun to write C++, but frustrating to get the compilerwork properly. Once you get the compiler set up right you'll be fine :)

Comment: @latedeveloper The IDE I am using is Eclipse Kepler

Comment: @JackDeeth I will do so very shortly :)

Comment: have you created a project?

Comment: @computers Frankly, Eclipse is a piss-poor C++ IDE (it's not even a particularly good Java IDE) and you would be better served using Code::Blocks, CLion or Visual Studio, or a text editor and the MinGW compiler to learn C++.